# How to use https request in session desktop project?

Tags: electron

Is there an existing request for feature?
I have searched the existing issues.
What feature would you like?
I cant' send request out.
This is example code.

```
try {
        const response: AxiosResponse<any> = await axios.get('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC,ETH&tsyms=USD,JPY,EUR&28475892d249fbdf4a8264d9f16b8e3e1377cc2b9056a78165576b08add3ae3c');
        const data: any = response.data;
        setPriceData(data);
        console.log("===priceData:", data, priceData)
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching crypto prices:', error);
      }
```

But I get this error:

> Error fetching crypto prices:
> AxiosError {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
> fetchCryptoData
> /home/smartfox/Docum…et/Dashboard.js:147
> GET [https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC,ETH&tsyms=USD,JPY,EUR&2847589…](https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC,ETH&tsyms=USD,JPY,EUR&2847589%E2%80%A6) net::ERR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED
> "

Anything else?
I cant send request out.
What's the problem and how to fix this problem?